# calculate grid path in Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have a grid amd can set four different movement directions for the player

- Vector2.up => (0,1)
- Vector2.down => (0,-1)
- Vector2.left => (-1,0)
- Vector2.right => (1,0)

I have a two dimensional array that contains `Cell` objects. `Cell` has a bool `isObstacle` to check if the player can move along or has to stop.

```
private Cell[,] mapCells = new Cell[10, 10]; // the map is 10x10
```

When filling the array I get 100 cells. When moving the player I want to check if he is able to move into a specific direction. I check this by some if statements

- the player is not moving outside
- the next cell is not an obstacle

My code

```
public Cell GetTargetCell(Vector2Int movementDirection) {
 Vector2Int targetCellIndex = new Vector2Int( /* currentPlayerPosX */ , /* currentPlayerPosY */ );

 while (targetCellIndex.x >= 0 &&
  targetCellIndex.y >= 0 &&
  targetCellIndex.x < mapCells.GetLength(0) &&
  targetCellIndex.y < mapCells.GetLength(1) &&
  !mapCells[targetCellIndex.x + movementDirection.x, targetCellIndex.y + movementDirection.y].IsObstacle) 
  {
  targetCellIndex += movementDirection;
  }

 return mapCells[targetCellIndex.x, targetCellIndex.y];
}
```

As you can see I check the next cell with my fifth if statement. The only problem is that if the while loop reached the maximum index for the array and I add a higher index I will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

```
!mapCells[nextX, nextY].IsObstacle // this might be out of range
```

Is it possible to prevent this error?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if your `targetCellIndex` with the `movementDirection` would be in the bounds. You currently check the "old coord" if they are in bound and then check the "new coord" to be `IsObstacle`. If i got your question correct

```
public Cell GetTargetCell(Vector2Int movementDirection) {
 Vector2Int targetCellIndex = new Vector2Int( /* currentPlayerPosX */ , /* currentPlayerPosY */ );

 while (targetCellIndex.x + movementDirection.x >= 0 &&
  targetCellIndex.y + movementDirection.y >= 0 &&
  targetCellIndex.x + movementDirection.x < mapCells.GetLength(0) &&
  targetCellIndex.y + movementDirection.y < mapCells.GetLength(1) &&
  !mapCells[targetCellIndex.x, targetCellIndex.y + movementDirection.y].IsObstacle) 
  {
  targetCellIndex += movementDirection;
  } else {
    //something wrong
    //do not move? to something else? your choice.
  }


 return mapCells[targetCellIndex.x, targetCellIndex.y];
}
```